# search in gmail returns wrong results?

Tags: gmail

Im currently doing a search in my GMail, namely

`in:all in:inbox -jaime`

Yet one of the answers contains the person "jaime".

**Is there a way to specify in a search "do not show any conversations where 'jaime' is involved"**

[image: jaime is not being ignored]

Comment: Questions on how to filter mail within Google Mail are not on topic here at Superuser.  If you want help with a desktop client filtering rule, we could help with that, but Google Mail is a web application.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if **A** message in a conversation is true, then the conversation will be displayed. So if the conversation has 50 messages, and only once does "jamie" not appear, then the entire conversation be returned by the results, and you can see all the messages in the conversation even those that mention jamie.

This is how the system must work when gmail is in the default conversation mode. This is also how most users would want the system to work for most of their searches. They want to see the conversation when condition1 and condition2 were true.

If you want to see the individual messages you would have to temporarily turn off the conversation view.

Note: your search example has a redundant part:

```
in:all in:inbox -jaime
```

tells gmail to return all conversations that are:

- has the label "all mail",
- and has the inbox label,
- and doesn't include jamie

The search

```
in:inbox -jaime
```

would achieve the same result. Because every conversation with the label  inbox  also has the label "allmail"

Comment: after some time, I realize that the real question is: is it possible to exclude whole 'conversations' contaning a term?